# Serve website root dynamically based on domain name

Tags: nginx

I have a server where I host multiple domain names. Depending on the domain name I'd like to serve files for a corresponding directory based on that domain name. For example:

`www.domainA.com` serves files from `/var/www/html/domainA.com`

`www.domainB.com` serves files from `/var/www/html/domainB.com`

etc. This way I do not have to edit my config file every time I add a site. In Apache I did it like this:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteMap    lowercase int:tolower
RewriteCond   ${lowercase:%{HTTP_HOST}}   ^(www\.)?(.*)$
RewriteRule   ^(.*) /var/www/html/%2/$1
```

How can I do the same thing in nginx?

Comment: Such questions are better asked on serverfault.stackexchange.com. SO is for programming questions.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I'll close this and post over there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Capture the domain name from the `$host` variable using a map outside of your server block.

```
map $host $domain_name {
   ~(?<domain>[^.]+\.[^.]+)$ $domain;
}
```

Then add the new `$domain_name` variable to your root statement. Note that `$host` is normalized to lowercase, so your domain directories should also be lowercase.

```
root  /var/www/html/$domain_name;
```

Make sure you've setup the server as the default.