# Alias/Rewrite failing with regular expression

Tags: nginx, nginx-location

With a location block as follows:

```
location ~ ^/x[0-9]/$ {
    alias /a/b/x$1/z/;
}
```

The HTTP request is continuously redirected to /a/b/x$1/index.html, without the z directory. But this only happens if the z directory exists! If it doesn't exist, it properly goes to:

```
/a/b/x$1/z/index.html
```

at which point it yields a 404 Error as expected.

Using a rewrite of:

```
rewrite '^x([0-9])/$' /x$1/z/;
```

results in the same behavior.

I am able to set the index directive as so:

```
index /z/index.html
```

and that works for loading my HTML page, but all subsequent requests fail due to not being in directory z. I need the alias to work, but for some reason it's not working correctly with regex. It's as if due to the inclusion of the $1 variable, the final directory gets gobbled up -- but only if it actually exists.

As per what I want to achieve ultimately: I want to be able to serve an arbitrary quantity of sites all with URI /x#, where # will be any positive integer from say, 1-999. On the server, the directory structure is /x#/z/index.html (e.g., /app42/dist).

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest capturing the site id in a map, then use that variable to have a dynamic root. You could probably adapt this: [serve-website-root-dynamically-based-on-domain-name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36393108/serve-website-root-dynamically-based-on-domain-name/36393784?s=4|39.7548#36393784)

Added benefit: Maps are evaluated early in the request cycle and will save you from some regex location confusion later.